# app.get blocks sequential query handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, url-routing, q

On my server side (Nodejs + Express) I have a route with long handling:

```
var apiRouter = express.Router();
apiRouter.use(compression());

apiRouter.get("/all", function(req, res, next){
    storage.getAllData().then(function(json){ res.json(json) }, next);
});

app.use("/api/data", apiRouter);
```

where getAllData reads a number of xml files from the hard drive in "parallel" (I'm using the [Q library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)) and then transform the xml into js ([xml2js library](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var path = require("path");
var extend = require("util")._extend;
var xmlDir = path.resolve(__dirname, "data");
var q = require("q");
var Parser = require("xml2js").Parser;
var readFile = q.denodeify(fs.readFile);

/**
 * Parses input xml-file and return promise with json
 * @param {String} fileName
 * @returns {*|Promise} parsed json
 */
function parse(fileName){
    var xmlFile = path.resolve(xmlDir, fileName);
    var parser = new Parser({
        mergeAttrs: true,
        explicitRoot: false,
        explicitArray: false
    });
    var parseXml = q.nbind(parser.parseString, parser);

    var deferred = q.defer();
    fs.readFile(xmlFile, function(err, data){
        if (err)
            deferred.reject(err);
        else
            deferred.resolve(data);
    });

    var time = process.hrtime();
    return deferred.promise.then(parseXml).then(function(json){
        var diff = process.hrtime(time);
        console.log(fileName + ": %d", (diff[0] * 1e9 + diff[1])/1e9)
        return json;
    });
}

/**
 * Get xml-file, parses it to json, handle raw result and return a promise with correct json
 * @param fileName
 * @returns {Promise|*} result json
 */
function parseRawItemizedJson(fileName){
    return parse(fileName + ".xml")
        .then(function(rawJson){
            var result = {};
            result[fileName] = rawJson.item;
            return result;
        });
}

function parseItemizedArray(fileNames){
    return q.all(fileNames.map(parseRawItemizedJson));
}

function getAllData(){
    return q.spread(
        parseItemizedArray([
            "contractors",
            "contracts",
            "districts",
            "facilities",
            "facilities_latlon",
            "info",
            "scope_of_works",
            "sequences",
            "subordinations",
            "subordinations_ovu",
            "type_of_works",
            "type_of_works_full"
        ]),
        function(){
            var result = {};
            for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
                result = extend(result, arguments[i]);
            }
            return result;
        });
}

module.exports = {
    getAllData: getAllData
};
```

From my client I make a call to "/api/data/all" and after short timeout (for debugging purposes) make GET-queries for 2 static files:
[image]

As you can see queries for static files hang auntil api-call completed. It seems that it's because of nodejs singlethread nature. Xml2js-processing of relatively big xml (~3mb) blocks processing of other queries. At least I think so at the moment. May be I'm doing it wrong way. So my question is how to process big files without freezing other client queries?

Comment: but node is single threaded, when you stop it on a break-point it stops everything, no? try inserting a very long sleep in to one of the routes and then query the other in the meantime.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutelly right. I rewrote the question to make things clearer.